# Distribuition Stella for holders

Tags: xlm

Please I read that there will be stellar distribution for those who have it in wallet, as mine are in exchange, I am not able to receive it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a scam. There is no such distribution planned. Be very careful with where you send your lumens.